# Balance checking (using discrete variables)

Tags: stratification, random-allocation

**Context**
I'm doing a field intervention, with 4 treatments and 1 control. I have done a stratified randomization beforehand to ensure that demographic characteristics (gender, age, income group) are evenly distributed across my treatment and control cells, i.e., I don't have a scenario where Treatment 1, for instance, is dispatched to all females, which would clearly not be ideal.

So this is what my table looks like.
[image]

**What happened**
I was advised to run some tests (e.g. T-tests or Mann-whitney) to ensure that the numbers are indeed balanced, since eyeballing the table alone is a low bar of evidence.

**The problem I have**
I want to pursue this guidance, but I have zero idea as to how to go about doing it.

For instance, T-tests/MW are about comparing means. But how would I compare means for ordinal data like the below, especially gender? And how would I compare them? Would I simply care about Control vs T1/Control vs T2/Control vs T3/Control vs T4 since I don't care about inter-treatment comparisons?

Appreciate if anyone can provide guidance to move me forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: this is a cross-tabulation table, hence use the chi square test to compare distribution of discrete variables.